How do i add memoization when calculating longest subsequence for an integer array?
I'm doing https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/
I know in theory that each index needs to be assigned a length but i'm having trouble coding it up using my iterative approach
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
function lengthOfLIS(nums) {
    let maxSubsequenceLength = -Infinity;
    const stack = [[-1, 0, 0]];
    const cache = new Map();

    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const [previousIndex, currentIndex, currentLength] = stack.pop();

        if (currentIndex === nums.length) {
            maxSubsequenceLength = Math.max(maxSubsequenceLength, currentLength);
        } else {
            const previousNumber = nums[previousIndex] ?? -Infinity;
            const currentNumber = nums[currentIndex];

            if (currentNumber > previousNumber) {
                stack.push([currentIndex, currentIndex + 1, currentLength + 1]);
            }

            stack.push([previousIndex, currentIndex + 1, currentLength]);
        }
    }

    return maxSubsequenceLength;
};



This is a dynamic programming problem, and you don't need an stack to solve it.
You can simply initialize an array for memoization:
The, you can create two for loops (i and j) and check every pair O(N ^ 2).
If nums[i] > nums[j]: you add one to the previously cached solution, using dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i], dp[j] + 1);



function lengthOfLIS(nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) return 0;

  const dp = new Array(nums.length).fill(1);

  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
        dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i], dp[j] + 1);
      }
    }
  }

  return Math.max(...dp);
}

console.log(lengthOfLIS([10, 9, 2, 5, 3, 7, 101, 18]));




To make it more efficient and optimized, you can add a binary search function:


function lengthOfLIS(nums) {
  function binarySearch(lo, hi, target) {
    while (lo <= hi) {
      const mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
      if (dp[mid] >= target) {
        hi = mid - 1;
      } else {
        lo = mid + 1;
      }
    }
    return lo;
  }

  const dp = new Array(nums.length).fill(Infinity);
  let lis = 0;
  for (const num of nums) {
    let lo = 0,
      hi = lis;
    lo = binarySearch(lo, hi, num);
    dp[lo] = num;
    lis = Math.max(lis, lo + 1);
  }

  return lis;
}

console.log(lengthOfLIS([10, 9, 2, 5, 3, 7, 101, 18]));




I know it's a dp problem and i was able to find many solutions on leetcode using that but i'm looking to solve it with stack + memoization, thanks for the help tho

@xqcccccccccc What would you like to cache/memoize?

i'm thinking to avoid repeated work, caching could be done to set max length for each index? sounds like your dp approach lol but i'm still wondering if that could be done in this dfs approach

@xqcccccccccc You're already caching the max length using  maxSubsequenceLength = Math.max(maxSubsequenceLength, currentLength);. You can use other methods, but there'll be a time complexity and efficiency issue that solution will fail for large test cases.
